# Edit SQL query to only include products from a term set by a variable

Tags: php, wordpress

Good day fellow coders

I am using Enovathemes product search plugin but need to make a small edit to the query which is where I have hit a brick wall.

**Question**
How can I edit the sql query so that it filters the products based on a custom taxonomy term set by the value of a custom field?

**Summary:**
The B2B system restricts the products the user sees based on a custom field value on their profile that is equal to a custom taxonomy term. So I need to limit the search results to only products in the term that matches the custom field value on their profile.

This is how I get the custom field value on the user profile and match it to the custom taxonomy term in my queries when displaying products.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$country = get_the_author_meta( 'country', $current_user->ID );
$term = get_term_by('slug', $country, 'product_country');
```

**What have I tried:**

I have tried to specify the term (via $country) in the sql query but this is not my strong point and after reading the codex and tons of tutorials I have given up. Now I have coder's block.

I have built a WP_Query which works perfectly but not within the sql query.

*Here is Enovathemes code that I am using. I have customised it to suit my needs but the basics are the same.*

```
 function search_product() {

        global $wpdb, $woocommerce;

        if (isset($_POST['keyword']) && !empty($_POST['keyword'])) {

            $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];

            if (isset($_POST['category']) && !empty($_POST['category'])) {

                $category = $_POST['category'];

                $querystr = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS r ON (p.ID = r.object_id)
                INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS x ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id)
                INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS t ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id)
                WHERE p.post_type IN ('product')
                AND p.post_status = 'publish'
                AND x.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
                AND (
                    (x.term_id = {$category})
                    OR
                    (x.parent = {$category})
                )
                AND (
                    (p.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' AND meta_value LIKE '%{$keyword}%'))
                    OR
                    (p.post_content LIKE '%{$keyword}%')
                    OR
                    (p.post_title LIKE '%{$keyword}%')
                )
                ORDER BY t.name ASC, p.post_date DESC;";

            } else {
                $querystr = "SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.*
                FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
                WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
                AND (
                    ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_sku' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%{$keyword}%')
                    OR
                    ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%{$keyword}%')
                    OR
                    ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%{$keyword}%')
                )
                AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
                AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product'
                ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC";
            }

            $query_results = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);

            if (!empty($query_results)) {

                $output = '';

                foreach ($query_results as $result) {

                    $price      = get_post_meta($result->ID,'_regular_price');
                    $price_sale = get_post_meta($result->ID,'_sale_price');
                    $currency   = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
                    $sku   = get_post_meta($result->ID,'_sku');

                    $output .= '<li>';
                        $output .= '<a href="'.get_post_permalink($result->ID).'">';
                            $output .= '<div class="product-image">';
                                $output .= '<img src="'.esc_url(get_the_post_thumbnail_url($result->ID,'thumbnail')).'">';
                            $output .= '</div>';
                            $output .= '<div class="product-data">';
                                $output .= '<div class="shado-12 product-title"><strong>Title:</strong> '.$result->post_title.'</div>';
                                if (!empty($sku)) {
                                    $output .= '<div class="shado-12 product-sku"><strong>SKU:</strong> '.$sku[0].'</div>';
                                }
                                if (!empty($price)) {
                                    $output .= '<div class="shado-12 product-price"><strong>Price:</strong> ';
                                        $output .= $currency;
                                        $output .= '<span class="regular-price">'.$price[0].'</span>';
                                        if (!empty($price_sale)) {
                                            $output .= '<span class="sale-price">'.$price_sale[0].'</span>';
                                        }
                                    $output .= '</div>';
                                }

                            $output .= '</div>';
                            $output .= '</a>';
                    $output .= '</li>';
                }

                if (!empty($output)) {
                    echo $output;
                }
            }
        }

        die();
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_product', 'search_product' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_product', 'search_product' );
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you could use WP Query (you could have done custom taxonomy filter) and makes things much cleaner for yourself. I am not against writing SQL but WP Query is well capable of handling most of the cases.

Comment: I agree in theory. I did try with a WP Query but could not get it to work within the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone with a similar problem arrives at my post. I was able to solve the problem by adding the .slug to the query and using the variable for it's value - works perfectly.

```
if (true) {

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$country = get_the_author_meta( 'country', $current_user->ID );

$querystr = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS r ON (p.ID = r.object_id)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS x ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS t ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id)
WHERE p.post_type IN ('product')
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND x.taxonomy = 'product_country'
AND t.slug = '$country'
AND (
    (p.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' AND meta_value LIKE '%{$keyword}%'))
    OR
    (p.post_content LIKE '%{$keyword}%')
    OR
    (p.post_title LIKE '%{$keyword}%')
)
ORDER BY t.name ASC, p.post_date DESC;";
```

}